# Adding Glassfish Server 5.0 in netbeans 8.2

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish

When i specify the directory of Glassfish 5.0, i get this message in the IDE :

> No usable default domain. Use Next to create a personal domain.

But, there is already a domain (domain1) and i don't want to create another one.

My question is : How to solve this problem ?! Or how can i make Netbeans find the existing domain ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of research, it turned out, that, to be able to perform such task, you have to run NetBeans 8.2 as Administrator (under Windows). If you do so, the "No usable default domain. Use Next to create a personal domain." will not be displayed.

I hope it can help other people.

Answer (score 0):

Run your NetBeans 8.2 as administrator then this problem will be solved..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).